# Datetime conversion in Sybase

Tags: sap-iq

I am new to sybase  and trying to convert YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS to YYYY-MM-DD in sybase?

I tried using Convert function but it does not work because of T in the datetime format.

Is there a option to achieve this using convert function?

Comment: have you tried `substring(<string>,1,10)` or `left(<string>,10)`?

Comment: I tried date(YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:MI:SS) and it worked. Thanks.